# How to Call External WebService using Proxy Host form JBOSS EAP 7.0.0

Tags: web-services, proxy, jboss7.x

We have couple of external third party web services to send business data. But the constrain is that,  those services need to be called from dedicated server (say 120.10.20.123 ).

Now any external service call need to be re directed through proxy server (120.10.20.123).

Can somebody please help me to understand how to achieve this functionality using JBOSS EAP 7.0.0

Thanks in advance.

Ajoy

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify in

> standalone.xml

at

> 

the following:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="http.proxyHost" value="yourProxyIpAddress"/>
    <property name="http.proxyPort" value="yourProxyPort"/>
    <property name="http.nonProxyHosts" value="localhost"/>  
</system-properties>
```

You can also do it programmatically but it's not related to question.

Or you could put a webserver to redirect the call to leave jboss clean.

Comment: Thanks, actually i am looking for programmatically approach, i am migrating current application from weblogic to jboss, and in weblogic it has been done programmatically. it reads proxy server details from database and use weblogic HttpTransportInfo class to set proxy address, and use stub._setProperty for re-direction.   ===>                                     
private void setProxyAndDestination(Stub stub, Proxy proxy) {
HttpTransportInfo info = new HttpTransportInfo();
info.setProxy(proxy);
stub._setProperty("weblogic.wsee.connection.transportinfo", info);setDestination(stub);
}